# iPhone Pong Advanced Deflection Angle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, collision-detection

I am currently developing a simple Pong game for the iPhone. Currently using CGRectIntersectsRect for the collision detection and as for the deflection of the ball when it hits the paddle, I just multiply the ball velocity with -1 (therefore reversing the direction of the ball).

What I am trying to do is to make it so that when the ball hits the paddle, it checks whether how far is the ball from the center of the paddle, and increases the deflection angle the further the ball is away from the center of the paddle. (E.g. In this case, the ball will be deflected back at 90 degrees no matter where it came from, as long as it hits the center of the paddle)

How am I suppose to do that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Clarification point of coordinates ...  90 degrees to what?  ... the incoming angle?  ... the paddle?  ... the normal of the paddle?

In physics, when we talk about optics and collisions, we usually refer to angle compared to the normal.  However such a frame of reference does not makes sense to me given what you have asked in the question.

Comment: The 90 degrees is the example of the deflection angle when the ball hits the exact center of the paddle.

This is how I wanted the ball to behave; to deflect the ball after it hits the paddle with the deflection angle in reference to the center of the paddle. If the ball touches the center of the paddle, it would deflect in a 90-ish degree and the further away from the center of the paddle, the deflection angle will increase, lets say, I want it to deflect at an angle of 45 degrees if it touches the left side of the paddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have given us are reference points (centre and edge).  What we need are a reference line from which to measure the new angle.  Additionally, what you are saying is not consistent and thus does not make sense.

I am guessing that what you are asking is a way to calculate the outgoing angle such that it is only a function of where it hit on the paddle.  If it hit the paddle centre, then irrespective of the incoming angle, it will bounce off at an angle of 90 degrees to the paddle.  If it hit the paddle edge, then irrespective of the incoming angle it will bounce off at an angle of 45 degrees to the paddle.

If so, then the following should do it (it is not the only way).

Assumption:  The paddle shape is a rectangle.

- Let L be the length of the paddle.
- Let K be a constant such that L / (2 * K) = 1 / sqrt(2).
- Let D be the distance from the centre of the paddle (may be + or -).

theta = pi/2 - asin (D / K);

This should give you an angle relative to the paddle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, what I want is to set it so that the outgoing angle is irrespective of the incoming angle, but according to where it lands on the paddle. I know it doesn't make any sense according to physics, but I'm trying to make it fun.

Thanks for the help, I think this is exactly what I needed.